# Binary matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, coding-theory

I am following an academic [lecture](https://youtu.be/M2Spgt3_3tE?list=PLzJaFd3A7DZs-wWfC6q8_4PxvDhcD2uTs&t=1255) on coding theory. The following matrix multiplication is done at the lecture. I paste a clear screenshot of the frame below.

[image]

As stated on the figure, I do not understand how such a simplification (indicated by the red arrow)  can be done. I would so much appreciate an elaborative answer which explains how this simplification. (the YouTube link opens the exact time he mentions this)

I truly appreciate for your valuable time.

Comment: I guess by "binary matrix" you mean that the elements of the matrix are from $Z_2$, the set of integers modulo 2. In that case, remember that the equation $x=-x$ always holds there.

Comment: @Qwertylicious I had missed something in the screenshot. It's as A.Sh says, being a binary matrix means that the elements are in $\mathbb F_2$ and thus $1=-1$.

Comment: @Qwertylicious: If the question you're asking is how do you get
$$v_0 + u_0 + u_2 + u_3 = 0$$
that's because
$$v_0 = u_0 + u_2 + u_3$$
so
$$v_0 + u_0 + u_2 + u_3 = (u_0 + u_2 + u_3) + u_0 + u_2 + u_3$$
which simplifies to zero, since the coefficients get reduced, mod 2.

Comment: please hold on im trying to understand what you all have said.

Comment: Okay, so even when two matrices are x-ored (mod 2) the result is similar to binary x-or result. @quasi if you post this as asnwer I can chose it to be the answer to this question.

Comment: I'm just asking, is this obvious in matrix multiplication? How could such a strategic proof (by quasi) be obvious to this lecturer? I guess I must be really poor in matrix theory.

Comment: @Qwertylicious It's just how the field behaves: $1=-1$. In practice probably no one thinks as quasi wrote. They just spelled out all of the details.

Comment: That the coefficients are mod 2 has to be specified somewhere. It's not automatic. So I'm assuming that was stated in the lecture.

Comment: It seems that there are still aspects that you don't understand (or perhaps I don't). Is it the matrix multiplication that you don't follow, or is it the modding out?

Comment: What I didn't understand was how he just simply brought a '0' into the scenario. But as you explained, I now understand that. 
but your last line only states that v0+ u0+u2+u3 = 0. 

How did he prove that V0+ V0+V2+V3 = 0? 

Shouldn't it be, 
V0 + V3+ V5 +V6 -=0?   Simply because U0 = V3 , U2= V5 and U3 = V6?

Comment: Are you sure that you're not misreading it? Some of what you think are "v's" look to me like "u's". In particular, I think the handwritten equation was intended as 
$$v_0 + u_0 + u_2 + u_3=0$$
not
$$v_0 + v_0 + v_2 + v_3=0$$

Comment: oh sorry, you are correct. I just misread it! thank you @Quasi!! you solved the mystery!!! I was too confused and misread what I had been reading right all along. I was frustrated with this doubt sometime now. Thank you really!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the coefficients are mod 2,

\begin{align*}
&v_0 = u_0 + u_2 + u_3\\[4pt]
\implies\;&v_0 - u_0 - u_2 - u_3 = 0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&v_0 + u_0 + u_2 + u_3 = 0\qquad\text{[since $-1 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$]}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

we know that
v0 = u0+u2+u3

- so, v0+u0+u2+u3 = 2 x v0
- in binary, 2 x 'anything' = 'anything' shifted left with '0' shifted in from right
- so the least significant bit is '0'